# I want to connect to an api and extract the data

Tags: python, pandas, api, data-analysis

I'm doing my own python analytics project on compiling and analysing data from this open-data source:

(https://data.gov.ie/dataset?q=homeless&api=true&sort=score+desc%2C+metadata_created+desc&theme=Housing)

I've never worked with api's or json's before.. all the info on google or YouTube video's always have an API key.. but I don't know how to get it

so far I've done this:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import time

API_KEY = requests.get('https://data.gov.ie/dataset?q=homelessness&api=true&theme=Housing&sort=metadata_modified+desc')
API_KEY.status_code
# this returns 200 which from google means connected status correct
```

Then I write this:

```
#make api call
response = API_KEY.json()
```

and get back errors:

```
JSONDecodeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/models.py in json(self, **kwargs)
    970         try:
--> 971             return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
    972         except JSONDecodeError as e:

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/json/__init__.py in loads(s, cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, **kw)
    345             parse_constant is None and object_pairs_hook is None and not kw):
--> 346         return _default_decoder.decode(s)
    347     if cls is None:
...
...
...
```

About The Project:
What I want it to connect to the data on homelessness in ireland (I would like the data to be easily updatable for future automatic updating but that's later on.. no idea how to do it yet).
Ireland is facing a serious crisis with homelessness and housing in general and I would like to see how it has worsened over the years and visualise it. Perhaps get some insight or the scale of the issue.
After I do some work with the project I will then import the data into tableau to do some more visualisation then publish my report to my LinkedIn.
Perhaps you can advise me if I should be trying to work with csv's or json's?

Any help as always would be sincerely appreciated.

Comment: That URL does not return json, it returns html.

Comment: Usually an `API key` is acquired by applying for it directly to the company. They usually have some sort of form to fill in and they send you the key if they approve it. However, it looks like for this website you don't need to have an API key to download the `csv` files. Take a look a [this link](https://opendata.housing.gov.ie/dataset/05f828a3-0832-4b05-810e-240408af15df/resource/9c52dcb3-be75-4227-9b0c-2ab8b13dd831/download/homelessness_report_january_2020.csv). It downloads the `csv` for `Homelessness Report January 2020 `

Comment: That URL is an html page that happens to include a link to their API and their API documentation at : https://docs.ckan.org/en/2.8/api/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An API key is generally used to access private data and/or make some write operations. It's not the case here, all data are public.

What you need is to get all data from 'Homelessness Report'. You have to proceed in 3 steps:

1. Query the database
2. Process and filter the result
3. Download and merge data

```
import requests

# 1. Query the database
q_url = 'https://data.gov.ie/api/3/action/package_search?q=homelessness&rows=100'
packages = requests.get(q_url).json()['result']

# 2a. Process results
df = pd.json_normalize(packages['results'], 'resources', 'title')

# 2b. Filter results
mask = df['title'].str.startswith('Homelessness Report') & df['format'].eq('CSV')
df = df.loc[mask, ['title', 'url']]

# 3a. Download data
data = {}
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    dt = pd.to_datetime(row.title.strip('Homelessness Report '))
    data[dt] = pd.read_csv(row.url)

# 4a. Merge data
out = (pd.concat(data, axis=0).droplevel(1).rename_axis('Date')
         .sort_index().reset_index())
out.to_excel('Homelessness Report.xlsx', index=False)
```

Output:

```
>>> out
          Date      Region Total Adults  ... Number of people with citizenship EEA/Uk Number of people with citizenship Non-EEA  Number of Child Dependants in Families
0   2019-01-01    Mid-East          254  ...                                      NaN                                       NaN                                     NaN
1   2019-01-01    Mid-West          338  ...                                      NaN                                       NaN                                     NaN
2   2019-01-01  North-East          162  ...                                      NaN                                       NaN                                     NaN
3   2019-01-01  North-West           52  ...                                      NaN                                       NaN                                     NaN
4   2019-01-01  South-East          316  ...                                      NaN                                       NaN                                     NaN
..         ...         ...          ...  ...                                      ...                                       ...                                     ...
436 2023-01-01    Mid-West          414  ...                                       45                                        32                                     NaN
437 2023-01-01    Midlands          148  ...                                       17                                        19                                     NaN
438 2023-01-01    Mid-East          437  ...                                       81                                        66                                     NaN
439 2023-01-01      Dublin         5946  ...                                     1506                                      1190                                     NaN
440 2023-01-01        West          321  ...                                       34                                        19                                     NaN

[441 rows x 21 columns]
```

Comment: you are a gem.. 
just a quick question, where did you get this from?
https://data.gov.ie/api/3/action/package_search?q=homelessness&rows=100
Thanks a million.